# is it possible to implement a matplotlib Slider into flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, plotly, matplotlib-widget

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO

img_src = 'https://unsplash.it/500/300'
response = requests.get(img_src)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))


img = np.asarray(img.convert('L'))


fig,ax = plt.subplots()
zlims = (np.percentile(img[:, :], 0), np.percentile(img[:, :], 100 - 0))
im = ax.imshow(img, aspect='auto',vmin=zlims[0], vmax=zlims[1])

threshold = 0.
axthreshold = plt.axes([0.2, 0.01, 0.65, 0.03])
sthreshold = Slider(axthreshold, 'clip', -.1, 15., 
                    valinit=threshold, valstep=None)

def update(val):
    ax.clear()
    zlims = (np.percentile(img[:, :], .1+val), np.percentile(img[:, :], 100 - (.1+val)))
    print(zlims[0],zlims[1])
    ax.imshow(img, aspect='auto',vmin=zlims[0], vmax=zlims[1])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    
sthreshold.on_changed(update)
update(threshold)
```

this creates a image where you can limit what range the colormap covers with a slider. As "clip" increases the color map variety lessens.

Im am pretty familiar with flask. Is there any way to implement something like this into flask? I would prefer matplotlib but I'm ok with trying anything.

Thanks!

--Update--- I realized that I don't want to refresh the page every time the picture is adjusted. I tried plotly javascript approach. I was happy until I realized the res is too low.

html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" /> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.11.1.min.js"></script>
    
    <style>
    .container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    </style>    
    </head>
<body>
<div class="container" id="myDiv"></div>
<div class="container">
    <input style="width:50%" id="slide" type="range" min="0" max="5" step="0.025" value=".1" name="name_of_slider">
</div>
<div class="container" id="sliderAmount"></div>
<script>
const z1 = JSON.parse('{{ Lsort | tojson }}');
const IMG = JSON.parse('{{ IMG | tojson }}');
var size = z1.length 
var qlower = z1[Math.ceil(size * .1 / 100) - 1]
var qupper = z1[Math.ceil(size * (100-.1) / 100) - 1]
var data = [
  {
    z: IMG,
    type: 'heatmap',
    colorscale: 'Viridis',
    zauto: false,
    zmax: qupper,
    zmin: qlower,
  }
];

var layout = {
  autosize: false,
  width: 1000,
  height: 600,
};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
var slide = document.getElementById('slide'),
sliderDiv = document.getElementById("sliderAmount");
slide.onchange = function() {
    sliderDiv.innerHTML = this.value;  
    var perc = this.value    
    var qlower = z1[Math.ceil(size * perc / 100) - 1]
    var qupper = z1[Math.ceil(size * (100-perc) / 100) - 1]
     
    var data = [
      {
        z: IMG,
        type: 'heatmap',
        colorscale: 'Viridis',
        zauto: false,
        zmax: qupper,
        zmin: qlower,
      }
    ];
    
    var layout = {
      autosize: false,
      width: 1000,
      height: 600,
    };
    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
}     
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

python:

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO
img_src = 'https://unsplash.it/500/300'
response = requests.get(img_src)
imgarray = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
imgarray = np.asarray(imgarray.convert('L'))


n = np.sort(imgarray.ravel()).tolist()
imgarray2D = np.flip(imgarray,axis=0)
imgarray2D = imgarray2D.tolist()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():  
    return render_template('clip.html',Lsort = n,IMG=imgarray2D)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Are you going to show us how it looks? Is loading something from `unsplash` critical to the question?

Comment: No, it’s not critical at all. I want to use only numpy and matpltlib. I only included pil and a online pic so anyone could give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in **Flask** or **Javascript**, but I did something (maybe clumsy!) similar to a **Matplotlib** slider using an HTML [range](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp) slider.

So, you put one of those sliders (with a class="watch" because you're watching it) and an HTML `img` in your web-page's HTML so you will have at least a slider in the `index.html`:

```
<input name="XXX" id="YYY" style="width:100%" class="watch" type="range" step="1" min="0" max="255" value="0">
```

and also an `img`:

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='default.png')}}" id="image" class="img-fluid">
```

Then attach an `onChange()` function to the slider like this so it gets called whenever the slider is moved:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".watch").on( "change input", fChanged);
  fChanged();   // do one initial update before user changes anything
});
```

You'll also need the jQuery CDN stuff. I used:

```
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And the function `fChanged()` gathers up the values of a number of sliders on the HTML page into a JSON to send to Flask endpoint called `/_refresh` like this:

```
{# https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/jquery/ #}
$SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};

function fChanged(eObj) {
   $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_refresh', {
        Hmin: $('#Hmin').val(),
        Hmax: $('#Hmax').val(),
        Smin: $('#Smin').val(),
        Smax: $('#Smax').val(),
        Vmin: $('#Vmin').val(),
        Vmax: $('#Vmax').val(),
        mask: jQuery("input[type='radio']").filter(":checked").attr("value")
      }, function(data) {
        $("#code").text(data.code);
        $("#image").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64,"+data.image);
      });
      return false;
}
```

You can see I had 6 sliders, a min and a max for each of Hue, Saturation and Value.

The **Flask** endpoint returned another **JSON** containing some code I wanted to display on the webpage and a base64-encoded PNG-format result image that I then used to update an HTML `img` by writing its `src` attribute.

The Python code for the `_refresh` endpoint looks like this - it does some other stuff with Hue, Saturation and Value that isn't interesting to you, but it shows how I processed the image and encoded it for returning as a JSON to the webpage:

```
@app.route('/_refresh')
def refresh():
    # DEBUG print(request.args)
    Hmin = request.args.get('Hmin')
    Hmax = request.args.get('Hmax')
    Smin = request.args.get('Smin')
    Smax = request.args.get('Smax') 
    Vmin = request.args.get('Vmin')
    Vmax = request.args.get('Vmax')
    mask = request.args.get('mask')
    # Do the image processing
    if 'localfilename' in session:
       im, HSV = loadImage(session['localfilename'])
    else:
       im, HSV = loadImage('default')
    lo = np.array([Hmin,Smin,Vmin], dtype=np.uint8)
    hi = np.array([Hmax,Smax,Vmax], dtype=np.uint8)
    mask = cv2.inRange(HSV, lo, hi)
    alpha = np.zeros((im.shape[0],im.shape[1]), dtype=np.uint8) + mask
    res  = np.dstack((im, alpha))
    # DEBUG 
    # cv2.imwrite('result.png', res)
    _, PNG = cv2.imencode(".png", res)
    b64img = encodebytes(PNG.tobytes()).decode('ascii')
    response =  { 
        'Status' : 'Success', 
        'image': b64img,
:        'code': render_template('code.py', Hmin=Hmin, Hmax=Hmax, Smin=Smin, Smax=Smax, Vmin=Vmin, Vmax=Vmax)
    }
    return jsonify(response) # send the result to client
```

You are not obliged to use **OpenCV** for the processing or base64-encoding, you can equally do all that with **PIL/Pillow** if you prefer - just ask, or look at any of my previous **PIL/Pillow** answers.

It might all be clumsy and misguided but it worked for me. I'll be glad too if someone else shows a better way!

---

By the way, if anyone is using **macOS** and trying to run the code in your question, the GUI with the image and slider pops up briefly and disappears. You can then spend ages reading about Matplotlib backends, how to list them, how to see what's available, how to change them, that you need a *"framework"* Python installation, or maybe don't and after around an hour, you discover that all you need is to add an extra line as follows:

```
...
ax.imshow(img, aspect='auto',vmin=zlims[0], vmax=zlims[1])
fig.canvas.draw_idle()
plt.show()                 # add this line if plot flashes and disappears
```

Comment: excited to give this a try. where do I find encodebytes and loadImage?

Comment: Sorry. You need `from base64 import encodebytes` at the top.

Comment: I loaded a default image from the webserver disk at startup and cached it in the Flask session and allowed the website user to upload their own to replace that default. So I made `loadImage()` to get that from the session. Underneath it is just exactly `im = cv2.imread('SOMEIMAGE.PNG')` So you need `import cv2` at the top also.

Comment: I tired working your answer with my set up, i ran into some issues I think i could figure out. Does you code load the browser every-time the html slider is adjusted? I wanted to avoid that but I should have made that more clear in my question .

Comment: It loads the default image from disk once at startup and then holds it as a Numpy array in memory. That gets overwritten with a new Numpy array if the user uploads a new image. Each time the slider is moved the server-side image is reprocessed and sent to the browser.

Comment: You can do image processing in the browser with OpenCVJS if that helps... https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/introduction-to-computer-vision-in-javascript-using-opencvjs